# Class expression or chain property for making inference in Protégé

Tags: ontology, protege

I have the following question:
In the ontology below, I have four word instances: `super`, `first-rate`, `word1` and `word2` and two compound instances: `super-word1` and `first-rate-word2`. `word` relate to compound instances with part-whole relationships. I want to infer that, since `super` is synonym of `first-rate`, then `super-word1` is synonym of `first-rate-word2`. I also do not want that `super-word1` is synonym of `first-rate` and that `first-rate-word2` is synonym of `super`.
Any help??? You can also replace both `word1` and `word2` with just one `word` instance.

PS. I am using Protégé, so a simple DL syntax would be appreciated.

Many Thanks
Nik

```
@prefix : <http://www.semanticweb.org/myontology#> .
@prefix owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#> .
@prefix rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> .
@prefix xml: <http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace> .
@prefix xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#> .
@prefix rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#> .
@base <http://www.semanticweb.org/myontology> .

<http://www.semanticweb.org/myontology> rdf:type owl:Ontology .

#################################################################
#    Object Properties
#################################################################

###  http://www.semanticweb.org/myontology#has_part
:has_part rdf:type owl:ObjectProperty ;
      rdfs:subPropertyOf owl:topObjectProperty ;
      owl:inverseOf :is_part_of ;
      rdfs:domain :compound ;
      rdfs:range :word .


###  http://www.semanticweb.org/myontology#is_part_of
:is_part_of rdf:type owl:ObjectProperty ;
        rdfs:subPropertyOf owl:topObjectProperty ;
        rdfs:domain :word ;
        rdfs:range :compound .


###  http://www.semanticweb.org/myontology#is_synonym_of
:is_synonym_of rdf:type owl:ObjectProperty ;
           rdfs:subPropertyOf owl:topObjectProperty ;
           rdf:type owl:SymmetricProperty ;
           rdfs:domain :word ;
           rdfs:range :word .


#################################################################
#    Classes
#################################################################

###  http://www.semanticweb.org/myontology#compound
:compound rdf:type owl:Class .


###  http://www.semanticweb.org/myontology#word
:word rdf:type owl:Class .


#################################################################
#    Individuals
#################################################################

###  http://www.semanticweb.org/myontology#first-rate
:first-rate rdf:type owl:NamedIndividual ,
                 :word ;
        :is_part_of :first-rate-word2 .


###  http://www.semanticweb.org/myontology#first-rate-word2
:first-rate-word2 rdf:type owl:NamedIndividual ,
                       :compound ;
              :has_part :first-rate ,
                        :word2 .


###  http://www.semanticweb.org/myontology#super
:super rdf:type owl:NamedIndividual ,
            :word ;
   :is_part_of :super-word1 ;
   :is_synonym_of :first-rate .


###  http://www.semanticweb.org/myontology#super-word1
:super-word1 rdf:type owl:NamedIndividual ,
                  :compound ;
         :has_part :super ,
                   :word1 .


###  http://www.semanticweb.org/myontology#word1
:word1 rdf:type owl:NamedIndividual ,
            :word .


###  http://www.semanticweb.org/myontology#word2
:word2 rdf:type owl:NamedIndividual ,
            :word .


###  Generated by the OWL API (version 4.5.9.2019-02-01T07:24:44Z) 
https://github.com/owlcs/owlapi
```

Comment: If whenever A holds, you want B to be implied, you have to add the axiom A subclass B. If A and B are complex class descriptions, you have to add a GCI. If this is not enough help, then please add your experimental ontology. See [how to provide minimal complete reproducable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Otherwise I have to create the ontology to give you an exact answer.

Comment: Note that in the original question the inferences were required on classes and not individuals. Hence my comment regarding the need to use GCIs.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a minimal ontology that will achieve these inferences:

```
@prefix : <http://www.semanticweb.org/myontology#> .
@prefix owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#> .
@prefix rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> .
@prefix xml: <http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace> .
@prefix xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#> .
@prefix rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#> .
@base <http://www.semanticweb.org/myontology> .

<http://www.semanticweb.org/myontology> rdf:type owl:Ontology .

:has_part rdf:type owl:ObjectProperty .


:is_synonym_of rdf:type owl:ObjectProperty ;
           rdfs:subPropertyOf owl:topObjectProperty ;
           rdf:type owl:SymmetricProperty ;
           owl:propertyChainAxiom ( :has_part
                                    :is_synonym_of
                                  ) .

:first-rate rdf:type owl:NamedIndividual .

:first-rate-word2 rdf:type owl:NamedIndividual ;
              :has_part :first-rate .

:super rdf:type owl:NamedIndividual ;
   :is_synonym_of :first-rate .

:super-word1 rdf:type owl:NamedIndividual ;
         :has_part :super .
```

The key bit is the following:

```
:is_synonym_of rdf:type owl:ObjectProperty ;
      rdfs:subPropertyOf owl:topObjectProperty ;
      rdf:type owl:SymmetricProperty ;
      owl:propertyChainAxiom ( :has_part
                               :is_synonym_of
                              ) .
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I have already tried that. The problem is that it infers also that super-word1 is synonym of first rate and first-rate-word2 is synonym of super, which both I do not want.

Comment: Then mention that in your question.